# Applications uses more than 100% of volume

Tags: windows, audio

I'm having a little problem with my computer.

Some applications on Windows are using more than 100% of volume. I haven't done anything to allow this, just happened randomly at first but now its almost every time. It's not a hardware problem because its appearing at Volume mixer.

Any information on how to solve this would help.